# GoCSV: concatenate 2 csv columns into a single struct member

Tags: csv, go

Can I concatenate 2 csv columns into a single struct member with [Go CSV](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv)?

CSV format is like this.

```
colA, date, time, colB
A1, 2017-04-14, 09:50:10, B1
A2, 2017-04-14, 09:50:20, B2
```

I would like to map this CSV into the struct

```
type MyStruct struct { 
    ColA       string `csv:"colA"`
    DateTime   string  // <- like "2017-04-14 09:50:10"
    ColB       string `csv:"colB"`
}
```

How can I do this with Go CSV or another way in Go?

Answer (score 2):

(a) I don't think there is a supported way to do this. However you *could* implement a custom reader that merges fields into each other. Rather proprietary, I wouldn't recommend it.

(b) Why not simply add a method to MyStruct that returns the merged values?

```
type MyStruct struct { 
    ColA       string `csv:"colA"`
    ColB       string `csv:"colB"`
    ColC       string `csv:"colC"`
}

func (m MyStruct) dateTime() string {
  return ColB+ColC
}
```

(c) Maybe use a little bit of shell-fu to pre-process the CSV before parsing it?